# Regulating SDL Sprite Speed C++

Tags: c++, performance, sdl, sprite

How do I regulate the SDL sprite speed in C++, I know it's something to do with the framerate, but I'm not 100% sure. I know how to do it in PyGame, but SDL & C++ are slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend following the lazyfoo tutorial on this.